# Is it possible to add an event listener to an html element from inside a js class that calls a function inside that class?

Tags: javascript, class, addeventlistener

I created a tooltip class that works fine when I hard code the event listener on the  tag.  I'd like to encapsulate the event listener into the class instead of having to add it on the  tag for each page I use it on.  My problem is I haven't been able to figure out the correct syntax to add the event listener inside the class.  I've researched a lot of questions here and looked at whatever documentation I could find.  That has turned up a lot of potential solutions but none have worked to date.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The tooltips work as expected when I use the following code.

```
<script>var tt = new ToolTip();</script>
<body onmouseover="tt.showToolTip(event)">
```

The start function within the class is used to start the event listener.
I'm getting the console.log output so I know I'm making it to this point.
Since the start function is called from the constructor.  I thought maybe because the class wasn't finished instanciating yet that was the issue.  I removed the call to start() from the constructor and added a call to start() after instanciating the tooltip.  i.e. tt.start();.  No joy...

Below are 4 different ways I have tried to get the event listener created within the class, to no avail.

```
start() {  // adds the event listener to the <body> tag for this tooltip instance
  console.log("in tooltip start function");
  document.body.addEventListener("onmouseover", (evt) => {this.showToolTip(evt)}, 
    {signal: this.#abortController.signal}, false);
// Took the abort controller code out of these 3 for readability
// document.body.addEventListener("onmouseover", this.showToolTip(), false);
// document.body.addEventListener("onmouseover", this.showToolTip(e), false);
// document.body.addEventListener("onmouseover", this.showToolTip.bind(this), false);
}
```

Comment: This can be closed as a **typo**. The event is `mouseover`, not `onmouseover`

Comment: Thanks, the <script> tag was just a typo in asking my question, it isn't like that in the code, obviously since it works that way.  But on the other response that fixed the problem.  Thanks much glad it was an easy fix.  Have a great day!